# On Edit function doesn't work when cells are pasted into on Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm working on spreadsheet and used the below `onEdit` function to populate 2 timestamps when cells are edited. However when the cells are pasted into it doesn't trigger the timestamp. Is there any other function the will trigger when cells are pasted into, so when the value changed in a cell?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "BOM" && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    if (e.range.columnStart == 1) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 30).setValue(new Date());
    } else if (e.range.columnStart == 20) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 31).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "BOM" && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    let l = e.range.rowEnd - e.range.rowStart + 1;
    if (e.range.columnStart == 1) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 30, l).setValue(new Date());
    } else if (e.range.columnStart == 20) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 31, l).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will it fire on `Ctlr+V` event?

Comment: A paste is an edit by a user

Comment: The last edition is genial.

Comment: "A paste is an edit by a user" - perhaps but an Event Object `value` is not returned if a value is pasted.

Comment: I just did a paste in row 2 column1 and I logged an event Object.  No value was returned but range, source and user info was returned and the script logs date in the appropriate location.   There's no requirement for a value in the script.